# I can't find my module in Odoo

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

I have created a module in Odoo 8 following a tutorial. I activated the technical features in Users then I've updated the module list but it doesn't appear in the list.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Track the following:

- checkout `__init__.py`, `__openerp__.py` files
- weather any server track-back appear or not
- find the path of addons module
- is your module is at same place or path?
- give read/write/execute permission for that module
- restart your server
- Go to browser, from GUI, `Setting => Modules => Update Modules List =>` and Click on Update button
- Now go to `Setting => Modules => Local Modules =>` remove Apps filter on right hand side and type your module name

I hope after do these you will find your module.

Comment: I can find it now, Thank you so much

Comment: If you can't find `Setting => Modules => Update Modules List`, go to Users,  your user, check `Technical Features`, then restart odoo with `./odoo.py --update=all`

Answer (score 0):

After tried everything in @Odedra's answer, It worked when I created a new DB -> restarted the server -> Updated the App List.