# I can't find my module in odoo 8

Tags: ubuntu, odoo, openerp-8

My goal is to customize the HR module of odoo 8.

My odoo 8 is installed on ubuntu machine.

I create a new module in addons-path (/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons ) by the follow command :

> odoo.py scaffold hr_customization /opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons

I change the owner of the folder as odoo.

This is the **__init__.py** file

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import hr_customization
import controllers
import models
```

and the **__openerp__.py** file

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
{
'name': "hr_customization",

'summary': """
    customize HR module""",

'description': """
    Long description of module's purpose
""",

'author': "MediOS",
'website': "http://www.MediOS.com",

# Categories can be used to filter modules in modules listing
# Check    https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/master/openerp/addons/base/module/module_data.xml
# for the full list
'category': 'Uncategorized',
'version': '0.1',

# any module necessary for this one to work correctly
'depends': ['hr',],

# always loaded
'data': [
    # 'security/ir.model.access.csv',
    'templates.xml',
],
# only loaded in demonstration mode
'demo': [
    'demo.xml',
],
}
```

From setting, I checked the technical feature, then, I update the modules list, but when I search my module I get nothing!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you try to check with the restart the ODOO server in your case ??

Comment: how can I restart it? because I don't find a solution, I try suggestion without success

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29930632/i-cant-find-my-module-in-odoo/29931024#29931024 might be this will helpful to you.

Comment: I followed these steps one by one  but I do not find my module. 
I doubt that the problem is with ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

For me it sounds, that your additional addons folder isnot in your openerp-server.conf

`/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons`   *isnt a default addons path*

Try to start your server with
    `../odoo.py ---addons-path /opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons`

or input your path to openerp-server.conf
   `addons_path=/opt/odoo/addons/,/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/`

After writing to openerp-server.conf restart server with 
`../odoo.py -c openerp-server.conf`
optional you can directly update your module in special db
`../odoo.py -c openerp-server.conf -d your-db -u your-custom-module`